# Chrome scroll issue inside facebook page tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, scroll, facebook-page

I'm loading data on scroll inside facebook page tab. It works well in all browser including IE. But in chrome it is not working.

My code to load data on scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
{
       $.get($('#cmn_scroll_path').val(),{'index': index1,'size':size,'search':search}, function(data){
             $(".scroll-data").append(data); //append received data into the element
             scroll_flag = true;
        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                    $('.loading_image').hide(); 
                    //alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
        });           
}
```

});

it is not coming inside `$(window).scroll(function()` in windows chrome. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed window to document it worked:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
if($(document).scrollTop() + $(document).height() >= $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
{
       $.get($('#cmn_scroll_path').val(),{'index': index1,'size':size,'search':search}, function(data){
             $(".scroll-data").append(data); //append received data into the element
             scroll_flag = true;
        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                    $('.loading_image').hide(); 
                    //alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
        });           
}
```